# What is this blank quest for?

Tags: guild-wars-2

The item with the bronze star.

[image]

It showed up when the **Frost and Fire** update went live. I've logged in and out, map changed etc but nothing seems to update it.

Is this a quest yet to be announced or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bronze star is a UI element that was accidentally introduced in the last update before it was meant to be displayed. It was supposed to be removed in a subsequent patch, but to date Arenanet still hasn't been able to do so.

Here's a [Reddit post](http://www.reddit.com/r/Guildwars2/comments/17j7b4/update_notes_jan_29/) detailing the fixes in the latest patch. Note the following line:

> Hid blank world-event UI for Temple of the Silent Storm Week

This was later removed from the [official forum patch notes](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Game-Update-Notes-January-28-2013#post1326255) when it was discovered that the star was still there for players.

**Update**: Another patch was released on January 30th which has now solved the issue. Here are the [official patch notes](https://forum-en.guildwars2.com/forum/info/news/Game-Update-Notes-January-28-2013#post1336820) which mention the fix.